# Get extra and modified file from git repository?

Tags: git

In my home folder I have unpacked a linux kernel tarball (linux-3.0.26.tar.bz2) downloaded from www.kernel.org. In "branch" at git://example.com the same kernel version is found but with a few files modified and some added.

Is it possible to download only the added and changed files that is not found in my unpacked tarball, so I only have to download a few kilobytes?

I have read about the "git fetch" command but I have not had any success with it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but if you have an older version of a Git Repository, you use git pull to fetch AND merge into your current local repo.

Answer (score 1):

**You can not update any unversioned source from any repository** directly and easy.

You still **can to try to create and define relation** between you *heap of files* and external *repository*

1. Create local, own Git repo
2. Place your source it it
3. Define for you repository remote (according to requirements)
4. Try to sync remote repo with your by fetching or pulling (but I can't predict results and amount of traffic and time consumed)

Comment: The amount of traffic is probably still large compared to a completely fresh checkout, given the incredible code turnover in the Linux kernel. I don't think the extra effort will be worth it, but +1 anyway.

Comment: @larsmans - I just *answer on asked question*, don't play for DecisionMaker